# How do I add Akka library to jupyter-scala so I can use it in the notebook?

Tags: scala, akka, jupyter

I want to use Akka inside jupyter notebook running jupyter-scala kernel. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `classpath.add()` to include the Akka library you want to use, then, as with any Scala program, import the classes as needed. `classpath.add()` takes one or more arguments that resemble [sbt library dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Dependencies.html). For example, if you want to use the `akka-actor` library, enter the following in your notebook:

```
classpath.add("com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.4")

import akka.actor._
```

The below screenshot shows the use of the above commands in a Jupyter notebook with the jupyter-scala kernel installed:

[image]

Comment: When I try it, I get an error: "cmd0.sc:1: not found: value classpath"

Answer (score 1):

If the classpath method doesnt work, you can add library using `ivy`:

```
import $ivy.`com.typesafe.akka::akka-actor:2.5.4`
```

Not sure if this is the best way, but it works.